# Integrating method using Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

Is there any particular name for the  integrating method shown in this video.
[video link](https://youtu.be/W4X74fjfnss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that method is called something like "Differentiating under the integral sign."  If you search for this on the web, you'll find some additional information, for example:  https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/

I hope this helps.